# Solve the overlap region of 2 triangles to minimize distance.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization, triangles

## Setup

We are given 2 triangles and a line such that one edge in each triangle is contained in that line. These 2 edges are such that they might overlap but their union forms a single continuous edge, i.e there are no "holes" between the 2 triangles.

Our goal is to modify the vertices of the triangles that are in the edge in such a way that the intersection at the line is empty and all points inside one triangle are closest to the final vertex of that triangle.

That's probably confusing so let's see a picture:

[image]

Given that setup, we seek to move the vertices $C,E,D,F$ into $C',E',D',F'$ such that $\overline{CD} \cup \overline{EF} = \overline{C'D'} \cup \overline{E'F'}$. With the added restriction that if $p \in \overline{C'D'}$ then $p$ is closer to $H$ than $K$ and if $p \in \overline{E'F'}$ then $p$ is closer to $k$ than $H$.

We can assume the triangles are coplanar, we can assume that they lie on the same side, we can assume no degenerate triangles. We cannot assume $H$ and $K$ are different nor that the other points do not overlap.

## My "Solution"

It's in quotations because if this worked there would be no need to ask for help.

Given an arbitrary setup that obeys the above and breaking the rule of assuming the "origins" ($H$ and $K$) are not necessarily different. We can construct the perpendicular bisector to the line $\overline{HK}$ as in this picture:

[image]

Then for each of $E$ if $\vec{HE}\cdot \vec{LM} > 0$ (i.e it's on the left side of the bisector) we set $E'=M$. For $F$ we execute the same test (i.e if it's on the left of the line we set it to $M$).

We then do a similar test for $C$ and $D$ except this time we check if they are on the right side of the bisector.

If a triangle becomes degenerate after this process it's fully removed.

i.e if you get this:

[image]

You set $D' = F$ and entirely remove $EKF$ (which is intended since all points are now closer to $H$).

## Problem

Aside the fact I am breaking an assumption to get this working, it seems this method has multiple blindspots, a randomly generated data set shows that problems occur in edge cases when for example 2 of the points overlap, the bisector is parallel to the line and a plethora of other tiny little things. I am wondering if someone can come up with a better solution.

For the sake of clarity, this is what the solution to the example would look like:
[image]

### Explicit formulation:

Given a line segment $\overline{AB}$, you are given 2 triangles $CHD$ and $EKF$ such that $\{C,D, E, F\} \subset \overline{AB}$ (i.e the 4 points lie on the interior of the segment). And $\{H, K\} \not\subset \overline{AB}$.

We seek to find 4 new points ${C', D', E', F'}$ such that $|\overline{C'H}| < |\overline{C'L}|$; $|\overline{D'H}| < |\overline{D'L}|$; $|\overline{E'L}| < |\overline{E'H}|$; $|\overline{F'L}| < |\overline{F'H}|$.

That also satisfy $\overline{C'D'} \cup \overline{E'F'} = \overline{CD} \cup \overline{EF}$ and $\overline{C'D'} \cap \overline{E'F'} = \{p\}$ where $p \in \overline{AB}$, in other words, the 2 resulting segments overlap only at their boundary point and nowhere else.

It is possible that in certain cases that one of the 2 triangles cannot satisfy all of these restrictions(see the third figure). In such cases have the other triangle satisfy its conditions and mark the second triangle as "useless".

Comment: The problem is hard to digest for me, as it is stated. Please also formulate it introducing the fixed (lines and) points of the problem in the right order at the beginning, then asking for the points to be found. Which are their properties explicitly in a final question?

Comment: @dan_fulea Let me know if the explicit formulation makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit, yes, we have now a clear framework. Here are some observations. If $H,K$ are in different half-planes w.r.t. the line $AB$, then reflect $K$ in $AB$ to reduce to the case they are in the same half-plane. Then there is a case when $HK\perp AB$, which should be omitted. Now construct $M\in AB$ as in the picture. The problem is that $C,D,E,F$ may all lie on the same side of $M$ on $AB$, e.g. on the ray $(MA$. Then, if i correctly understand the question, there is no good choice for $C',D',E',F'$.

Comment: @dan_fulea You understand the setup properly and also the theoretical problem. My practical problem I may have not conveyed properly yet.

I am answering the question "where on the given segment is $H$ closer to the line and where is $K$ closer to the line". So in the degenerate case you are mentioning, the correct answer is that only one of the 2 points is closer so the correct answer is to select the only point that statisfies it and ignore the other.

Comment: The specific challenge I have is, computing the answer mathematically. As I mentioned, my bisector approach suffers from multiple edge cases where it falls apart.

In other words, I need a way to compute the correct answer that is robust even in degenerate cases such as when the 2 intervals are identical.